# How do I incorporate this do-while loop into the overall Big O analysis of my algorithm?

Tags: c++, runtime, big-o

I'm doing problems on leetcode and was able to solve this one, but I'm not exactly sure what the Big O notation for my solution is. **Here is the problem:**

```
Given an array of integers 'nums' sorted in non-decreasing order, find the starting and ending position of a given target value.

If target is not found in the array, return [-1, -1].

You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

Example 1:
Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8
Output: [3,4]

Example 2:
Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 6
Output: [-1,-1]

Example 3:
Input: nums = [], target = 0
Output: [-1,-1]
```

**My code:**

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> searchRange(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int l = 0,m,h = nums.size()-1;
        vector<int> ans;
        ans.push_back(-1);
        ans.push_back(-1);

        while (l <= h) {
            m = (l+h)/2;
            if (nums[m] == target) {
                l = m-1;
                h = m+1;
                ans.at(0)=m;
                ans.at(1)=m;
                do {
                    if (l >= 0 and nums[l] == target) {
                        ans.at(0)=l;
                        l--;
                    }
                    else {
                        l = -99;
                    }
                    if (h <= nums.size()-1 and nums[h] == target) {
                        ans.at(1)=h;
                        h++;
                    }
                    else {
                        h = nums.size();
                    }
                } while (l >= 0 or h < nums.size());
                return ans;
            }
            else if (nums[m] < target) {
                l = m+1;
            }
            else {
                h = m-1;
            }
        }
        return ans;

    }
};
```

**My Thoughts:**

I used a binary search to locate the first instance of the target value so I know its at least O(logN), but what gets me confused is my inner do-while loop within the outer while loop. In class I was told the Big O notation of an algorithm will be, for instance, O(N^2) if there is a for loop nested within another for loop because for every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop executes N times, assuming N is used as the value in the terminating condition for both loops. However, in this case the inner do-while loop will begin executing for only one outer loop iteration if and only if the target value is even in 'nums'. Using the same logic from class, this leaves me unsure as to how the inner do-while loop effects the Big O because if its O(N*N) for a for loop whose nested for loop occurs N times for every outer loop iteration, then what would it be for my solution where the inner do-while loop can begin executing either only for a single outer loop iteration or not at all? O(logN * 1) = O(logN) seems to be a viable answer until I consider the fact that the worst case runtime for the inner while loop would be O(N) if 'nums' consisted of N elements that were all the target value. I'd imagine this would make the Big O notation be O(N * logN * 1) = O(N * logN), which would then make my solution invalid but I'm not very confidant in that answer. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use a binary search to locate the end points of the range as well.

Comment: Did your class not mention that doing something O(f(n)) followed by something O(g(n)) is O(f(n) + g(n))?

Comment: I believe it was mentioned but the notes I took and the textbook itself were apart of an online subscription for the quarter and I didn't realize I wouldn't have access to my notes once the quarter ended. I'm trying to review the material I learned in that class because I know Big O is very important to know and understand but its rather difficult to do without my notes. Do you have any recommendations for online sources or textbooks that cover the subject well?

Answer (score 1):

Your code complexity is  `O(log(N)) + O(N)`. As you can rearrange your code like below. Its not the code structure that determines the time complexity. Its how the program counter moves.

```
vector<int> searchRange(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int l = 0,m,h = nums.size()-1;
        vector<int> ans;
        ans.push_back(-1);
        ans.push_back(-1);
        bool found = false;
        //takes log(n) time
        while (l <= h) {
            m = (l+h)/2;
            if (nums[m] == target) {
              found = true;
              break
            }
            else if (nums[m] < target) {
                l = m+1;
            }
            else {
                h = m-1;
            }
        }
        if(found){
            // takes O(n) time.
            l = m-1;
            h = m+1;
            ans.at(0)=m;
            ans.at(1)=m;
            do {
                if (l >= 0 and nums[l] == target) {
                    ans.at(0)=l;
                    l--;
                }
                else {
                    l = -99;
                }
                if (h <= nums.size()-1 and nums[h] == target) {
                    ans.at(1)=h;
                    h++;
                }
                else {
                    h = nums.size();
                }
            } while (l >= 0 or h < nums.size());
        }
        return ans;

    }
```

This worst case can occur if all your entries are target and hence you need to traverse full array.
You can easily get the answer with `O(log(n))` if you use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range function, it uses `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` both of which are `O(log(n))`.

Comment: That's cool, I wasn't aware there was a function like that. Do you think it'd be possible to change my current code to get `O(log N)`? Using that function would be a lot easier but I'd rather code the solution myself as opposed to using something that is built in.

Comment: @odo Take a look at the implementation of lower_bound and upper_bound function as you have to implement something like that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound